# SelectNodes with XPath ignoring cases

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, case-insensitive

I have a problem finding elements in XPath that's contains a certain string ignoring character casing.

I want to find in a HTML page all the nodes with id contains the text "footer" ignoring it's write in uppercase or lowercase.

In my example I have a different html text like this:

```
<div id="footer">some text</div>
<div id="anotherfooter">some text</div>
<div id="AnotherFooter">some text</div>
<div id="AnotherFooterAgain">some text</div>
```

I need to select all nodes (or any combination in any case with the word "footer" in the id) with a XPath.

Currently I'm using this xpath but doesn't work for the UpperCase id's

```
"//*[contains(./@id, 'footer')]/@id"
```

I've done several tests with translate() but doesn't work as I expected.

Any idea?

**EDIT:** I'm using HtmlAgilityPack with works with the XPath 1.0 version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if you've tried this yet, but this is what I do for case sensitive contains searches:

```
//*[contains(translate(./@id,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'footer')]/@id
```

I saw you have found your solution, so I'm posting this answer in case others have the same issue.

Comment: This is exactly the solution that i found but i can't post it is because i can't reply to myself in, at less, 8 hours :S Thanks for the post!