# Xpath - Extracting multiple specific differnt parts of text strings from one text node

Tags: xpath

I have three samples of text nodes that and I want to extract three different parts of the text, using a universal x-path.

First

```
<p class="product-summary">
                This is an amazing game from the company Midway Games. Excellent gameplay. Very good game.
            </p>
```

Second

```
<p class="product-summary">
                New Line Cinema distributed this movie in 1995.
            </p>
```

Third

```
<p class="product-summary">
                New game from 2011, with new 3D graphics. This game was made by NetherRealm Studios.  
            </p>
```

The extraction should be either `Midway Games` or `New Line Cinema` or `NetherRealm Studios`
Note that the text node allways include just one company, never two or three (just one).

My try is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598912/xpath-how-to-extract-specific-part-of-the-text-from-one-text-node) but the problem is that it dosen't work nor include all three companies.

```
substring('Midway Games',1,12*contains(//p[@class='product-summary']/following-sibling::text()[1], 'Midway Games'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the input will only contain one of them, you can use `concat` to join the results.

```
concat(
  substring('Midway Games', 1,
      12*contains(//p[@class='product-summary'], 'Midway Games')),
  substring('Line Cinema', 1,
      11*contains(//p[@class='product-summary'], 'Line Cinema')),
  substring('NetherRealm Studios', 1,
      19*contains(//p[@class='product-summary'], 'NetherRealm Studios'))
)
```

You can remove the line breaks that I added for readability as you want.

I had to fix the query you provided: the text nodes are no `following-sibling`s, but children. Your XPath processor will query the (concatenated) text nodes below that element anyway as `contains` works on strings.

Comment: Thanks you so much Jens. This works very good. Should this work with DOMXpath?

Comment: If you speak of PHP's DOMXPath class: yes, they're using libxml that I tested against. Anyway, you might consider running multiple queries and add everything together in PHP, this would probably be cleaner code as this XPath hack.