# How to do a Python XPath case-insensitive search using lxml?

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing, lxml, lowercase

I am trying to match for country or Country using `lower-case` function in XPath. `translate` is kinda messy, so using lower-case and my Python version 2.6.6 has XPath 2.0 support I believe since lower-case is only available in XPath 2.0.

How I can put lower-case to use in my case is what I am looking for. Hope the example is self explanatory. I am looking for `['USA', 'US']` as output (both countries in one go which can happen if lower-case evaluates Country and country to be the same).

**HTML: doc.htm**

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name of the Country : <span> USA </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name of the country : <span> UK </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**Python :**

```
import lxml.html as lh

doc = open('doc.htm', 'r')
out = lh.parse(doc)
doc.close()

print out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(. , "Country")]]/span/text()')
# Prints : [' USA ']
print out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(. , "country")]]/span/text()')
# Prints : [' UK ']

print out.xpath('//table/tr/td[lower-case(text())[contains(. , "country")]]/span/text()')
# Prints : [<Element td at 0x15db2710>]
```

**Update :**

```
out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") , "country")]]/span/text()')
```

Now the question remains, can I store the translate part as a global variable 'handlecase' and print that global variable whenever I do an XPath?

**Something like this works :**

```
handlecase = """translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")"""

out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(%s , "country")]]/span/text()' % (handlecase))
```

But for sake of simplicity and readability, I want to run it like this :

```
out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(handlecase , "country")]]/span/text()')
```

Comment: From [the lxml XPath documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html): `lxml supports XPath 1.0`; thus, with lxml you are stuck with translate.

Comment: In that case, I am not sure why it isn't complaining when I use lower-case. I didn't have much luck with 'translate' either in this example scenario. Thank you!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804281/selectnodes-with-xpath-ignoring-cases/9805020#9805020)

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is more of a 'lower-case' discussion than translate. I actually got the translate to work by doing : out.xpath('//table/tr/td[lower-case(text())[contains( translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") , "country")]]/span/text()') . Mods may close this if lower-case can't be applied in this case. Thank you!

Comment: But lxml DOES complain if you use `lower-case()`: "lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Unregistered function". The code after "*I actually got the translate to work by doing..."* can't be right.

Comment: It works! handlecase = 'translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")' out.xpath('//table/tr/td[text()[contains(%s , "country")]]/span/text()' % (handlecase))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
   //td[translate(substring(text()[1], string-length(text()[1]) - 9),
                  'COUNTRY :',
                  'country'
                  )
        =
         'country'
       ]
        /span/text()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "//td[translate(substring(text()[1], string-length(text()[1]) - 9),
                  'COUNTRY :',
                  'country'
                  )
        =
         'country'
       ]
        /span/text()
       "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<html>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name of the Country : <span> USA </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name of the country : <span> UK </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected two text-nodes are copied to the output:**

```
 USA  UK
```

**Explanation**:

1. We use a specific variant of the XPath 1.0 expression that implements the XPath 2.0 standard function `ends-with($text, $s)`: this is:

.....

```
$s = substring($text, string-length($text) - string-length($s) +1)
```

.2. The next step is, using the `translate()` function,  to convert the ending 10-character long string to lowercase, eliminating any spaces or any ":" character.

.3. If the result is the string (all lowercase) "country", then we select the children text nodes (only one in this case) of the s=`span` child of this `td`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the easiest thing to get what you want would be just writing an XPath Extension function.

By doing this, you could either write a `lower-case()` function, or a case insensitive search.

You can find the details here: http://lxml.de/extensions.html

Comment: very nice answer, but you can't win without an example

Comment: I wasn't trying to win, just to help. I thought of giving an example, but it just seemed to me that the link has enough examples.