# Get most inner div either by specific class or id

Tags: html, xpath

I would like to get to most inner div in a html document that has the id or class containing "content".

What I have tried:

```
//div[@id[contains(.,'content') and not(*)]]
```

This works for getting the most inner div with an id containing "content".

Now I want to get the most inner div by id or class (depends on whats the most inner is) containing the id or class "content".

Sample data:

```
<body>
<div class="outerContent">
    <div id="moreContent">
        <div class="anotherContent">
            This is what I am looking for.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
<div class="outerContent">
    <div id="moreContent">
        <div id="anotherContent">
            This is what I am looking for.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Note that "This is what I am looking for" could be inside a div class conainting "content" or a div id containing "content".

Thank you!

Comment: please post an example of your XML and what you'd like returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses only XPath 1.0 expressions. My understanding is that XPath 2.0 isn't available.

**Use**:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'Content') or contains(@class, 'Content')]
       [not(descendant::div[contains(@id, 'Content') or contains(@class, 'Content')])]
```

This selects any `div` element whose `id` attribute has string value that contains the string `"content"`, or whose `class` attribute has string value that contains the string `"content"`, and that has no descendant `div` elements with this properties.

**Do note, that such thing as "the most inner div" may not be singular** -- that is, many `div` elements may exist such that they fulfill the conditions set in the question.

**If this is the case, and you need just one such `div` element (say, the 1st), you can use**:

```
(//div[contains(@id, 'content') or contains(@class, 'content')]
        [not(descendant::div[contains(@id, 'content') or contains(@class, 'content')])]
)[1]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//div[contains(@id, 'Content') or contains(@class, 'Content')]
       [not(descendant::div[contains(@id, 'Content') or contains(@class, 'Content')])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the first provided XML document:**

```
<body>
    <div class="outerContent">
        <div id="moreContent">
            <div class="anotherContent">
            This is what I am looking for.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<div class="anotherContent">
            This is what I am looking for.
            </div>
```

**With the second document, again the correct result is produced:**

```
<div id="anotherContent">
            This is what I am looking for.
        </div>
```

**Finally**, in case the comparisson for "Content" should be case-independet, use:

```
  //div[contains(translate(@id,'CONTE','conte'), 'content')
      or contains(translate(@class,'CONTE','conte'), 'content')
       ]
         [not(descendant::div
               [contains(translate(@id,'CONTE','conte'), 'content')
               or contains(translate(@class,'CONTE','conte'), 'content')
               ]
              )
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated.**

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this is how I would do it: `//descendant::div[last()][contains(@id,'Content')]`

If you need to check @id for any case, use the [translate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804281/selectnodes-with-xpath-ignoring-cases/9805020#9805020) around the `@id` part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear about your exact question, so I give two interpretations.

### No other `<div/>` elements fulfilling the predicates

The `<div/>` with either `@class` or `@id` containing 'content' which does not contain any other `<div/>` fulfilling this predicate. This allows other markup inside the `<div/>`.

```
//descendant::div
  (: either @id or @class contain 'content' :)
  [contains(lower-case(@id), 'content') or contains(lower-case(@class), 'content')]
  (: only inner-most div fulfilling this condition :)
  [last()]
```

### Nothing but text

There must not be any element nodes inside the `<div/>`.

```
//descendant::*
  (: only inner-most elements :)
  [last()]
  (: which are a div :)
  [local-name(.) eq 'div']
  (: and either @id or @class contain 'content' :)
  [contains(lower-case(@id), 'content') or contains(lower-case(@class), 'content')]
```

---

If you haven't got XQuery 2.0 support, there should not be any `fn:lower-case()` available. If so, you will have to strip it and replace 'content' by 'Content' for the data you provided.

If you've got XQuery 2.0 support, you could also use this as a predicate which is more extensible (much easier to add new attributes to the list and less redundant code):

```
[some $attribute in (@id, @class) satisfies contains(lower-case($attribute), 'content')]
```