# xpath cannot distinguish similar link text

Tags: java, html, xpath, webdriver

I have an html page with two links on it, with similar link text:

'**Office of Records**' and '**Brooklyn Office of Records**'

If I use this xpath, it will find the second link:
"//a[starts-with(.,'Brooklyn')]" - so far so good.

However, if use the same xpath but look for the first link (which starts with the word 'Office'), it doesn't work :
"//a[starts-with(.,'Office')]" - 'Unable to locate element'

I tried using regex ('^Office'), but that didn't work. 
I tried 'contains' instead of 'starts-with', but that also didn't work since one string is a substring of the other.

Any suggestions welcome!

EDIT

I read the spec, and it is as I assumed it would work: if string1 starts with string2, it returns true: starts-with(string1, string2)

I mocked up some xml to test this in the online tester:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <note>
        <record>
          <a>Office</a>
          <a>Brooklyn Office</a>
        </record>
    </note>
```

I have found no way to point to the first node ('Office') through 'starts-with', or 'contains'

Comment: Take a close look at the HTML, and verify that the first link text actually starts with "Office", and doesn't have spaces or other characters at the start.

Comment: Text has been verified.  I also just tested this in an online xpath tester (http://www.xpathtester.com/test), and it returns the same results; starts-with doesn't actually seem to do what the name suggests'.

Comment: Here's the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with

Comment: Whenever I see behavior that doesn't seem to follow the spec, I try really hard to figure out what *I have done wrong.* Including writing a sample program that clearly follows the spec (ie, you construct your own document, and then apply the XPath to it). Because the likelihood that a commonly-used library only works occasionally is vanishingly small.

Comment: Also, it's case sensitive. Make sure you're not looking for "Office" instead of "office", or apply a translate() to move everything to upper/lowercase before checking for substrings. [Look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804281/selectnodes-with-xpath-ignoring-cases/9805020#9805020) if you want to see how

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
So, this didn't work: 
    //a[starts-with(.,'Office')]

This did: 
    /*/record/a[starts-with(.,'Office')]

Answer (score 0):

`//a[text()='Office of Records']` and `//a[text()='Brooklyn Office of Records']`

Do not overcomplicate things ;)