# Using XPath with node attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the very basics of XPaths down, but am having some trouble in determining if the following is possible in C# code using an XPath (or if I need to move it out into other code, as I currently have done).

I have an XML Document that consists of the following structure:

```
 <xml>
     <parameters>
        <setParameter name="SomeName" value="SomeValue" />
     </parameters>
 </xml>
```

Where there are multiple set Parameter values.  Now what I need to do is only retrieve those setParameter nodes that contain certain values for the name attribute.  I may have a list of possible matches for these values, but they won't be full matches, they will be values the node's name attribute must contain.

For example in the structure code above, if I had a value of 'men' to match, it would come back with the node, as 'men' is contained in 'SomeName'

What is the shorthand to do this?

Comment: do you have an xpath example?

Comment: very simple at: "parameters/setParameter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the value of all attributes named `value` for all elements named `setParameter` having a `name` attribute's value containing `men`:

```
//setParameter[contains(@name, 'men')]/@value
```

- //setParameter

Retrieves all nodes named `setParameter` (can be replaced with `/xml/parameters/setParameter`)

- [...]

Checks an attribute for the current node selection

- contains(@name, 'men')

Returns true if the `name` attribute's value contains `men`

- /@value

Retrieves the `value` attribute's value.

Comment: Is this case-insensitive?

Comment: @Polyfun No, it's case sensitive. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9805020/3283203) for case-insensitiveness.

Comment: OP wanted a case-insensitive match.

Comment: @Polyfun I must be sleepy, but I don't see this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to match an attribute with a wildcard, but you could use the `contains` method, something like:

```
//parameters/setParameter[contains(@name, "stringexample")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your `XPath` version this might work or might not:

```
//setParameter[matches(@name,"men", "i") or matches(@name,"else", "i")]
```

This should match `<setParameter>` with `name` attribute that contains `"men"` or something `"else"`. It is case-insensitive

Try and let me know the result